# Development of the Taylor series of $f(z)= \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ around the point $z_0 = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried with: $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ = $\frac{1}{(1+zi)(1-zi)}$ 
Then $w = z-1$ and $z=w+1$ ... $\frac{1}{(1-(w+1)i)(1+(w+1)i)}$ = $\frac{A}{1-wi-i} + \frac{B}{1+wi+i}$
-> $A=1/2$ and $B=1/2$ I put A and B in fraction and I get:
$\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(i)^n(z)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{∞}(-i)^n(z)^n)$

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It needs to be written in powers of $z-1$.

Comment: How can $\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(i)^n(z)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{∞}(-i)^n(z)^n)$ be "ok" as an expansion around $z_0=1$? Do you mean $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{∞}(i^n+(-i)^n)w^n$, with $w=z-1$? Then no, this is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{z^2+1}=\frac1{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{z-i}-\frac1{z+i}\right)=$$

$$\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{z-1+i-i}-\frac1{z-1+1+i}\right)=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{1-i}\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}{1-i}}-\frac1{1+i}\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}{1+i}}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1+i}{4i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(z-1)^k}{(1-i)^k}-\frac{1-i}{4i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(z-1)^k}{(1+i)^k}$$

as long as $\;\left|\frac{z-1}{1\pm i}\right|<1\iff |z-1|<\sqrt2\;$ , which seems a reasonable assumption since we're only interested around $\;z=1\;$ .